# Bouncing Balls in d3

Tags: javascript, math, d3.js, game-physics

Hi I am using [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/atul-github/0019158da5d2f8499f7f) in order to have multiple balls (with the same size) that bounce inside a frame.

The thing is that i need to change it in a way that after 2 balls have collided they will bounce back into a random direction and not necessarily the "physics" way. of cource the balls mustn't overlap each other at any time.

Would love to hear some suggestions on how to create that random movement after colliding.

**edit**

forgot to mention, the balls should always remain on the same speed, Because all the balls in my case have the same radius they are also on the same speed. So simply incresing or decreasing the vx and vy won't do.

**edit 2**

In my opinion and according to some logics I made, the course should be a random angle in a range of 180 degrees from the contact point of the ball.
The thing is I don't know how to make these calculation, get each ball contact point and take the range from there

Answer (score 2):

One solution, would be to change the angle of action post collision

```
    if ( CheckCollision(ball1, ball2) ) {
        //change the angle of both the balls
        console.log(ball1.aoa, ball2.aoa, "old");
        var a1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);//change the angle using random
        ball1.aoa = Math.PI / a1;

        var a2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);//change the angle using random
        ball2.aoa = Math.PI / a2;
        console.log(ball1.aoa, ball2.aoa, "new");
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/KWsBiJGccbqVZgZFNieP?p=preview)

Comment: Changing the angle won't change the balls course, only changing the vx and vy

Comment: It won't as incresing or decreasing the vx or vy will change the balls speed, something I can't have

Comment: well you dont want to change the speed nor its angle ...but would like the change the course/direction...hmmm...i dont know if its possible..

Comment: I do wish to change the angle, that what it's all about. I probably wasn't understood. I am saying that after randoming the angle the vx and vy should be calculated by the new aoa and jumpSize. The main problem is that the angle randoming may cause problems, as I am not allowed the balls to overlap or to simply switch place. For example, randoming the angle might cause the balls to move in the same route, which will cause a little jump between the two balls

Answer (score 2):

after the line

```
        if ( CheckCollision(ball1, ball2) ) {
```

The code performs the calculations to determine the new velocities for ball1 and ball2 before setting them here:

```
//set velocities for both balls
            ball1.vx = vx1;
            ball1.vy = vy1;
            ball2.vx = vx2;
            ball2.vy = vy2;
```

If you don't want them to be realistic, then you can simply change vx1, vy1 and vx2 and vy2 to a random value. You will probably have to retain this code

```
//ensure one ball is not inside others. distant apart till not colliding
            while (CheckCollision(ball1, ball2)) {
                ball1.posX += ball1.vx;
                ball1.posY += ball1.vy;

                ball2.posX += ball2.vx;
                ball2.posY += ball2.vy;
            }
```

to ensure that you don't draw the balls inside each other. This however might mean that the balls will "phase" through one in a random way

Comment: The thing is that because the balls are with the same radius, their speed is the same. the speed should stay the same at all times. if I will increase or decrease the vx or vy the speed will change as well and I need them to remain in their initial speed